# Arrows of clock made with CSS work incorrectly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have made an analog clock using `CSS` and rotate its arrows. This works fine but the problem appears when I set starting time. for example, if it's 12:00pm, second arrow does full spin in 60 seconds, minute arrow does the same in 3600 seconds and hour hand does it in 43200 seconds. But, if the time is 3:15:20pm, second arrow should start moving from 20 seconds. In this case I use `css` to set starting point by `rotate(120deg)`. But my arrow rotates from digit 4 to 12 for 60 seconds anyway and simply jumps to the starting point after that. How do I fix this?

See the fiddle, there is only the second arrow but I think problem is visible:
https://jsfiddle.net/vaxobasilidze/fdn28u7g/2/

```js
function setTime(){
    var time = new Date($.now());
    var hour = time.getHours();
    var minute = time.getMinutes();
    var second = time.getSeconds();
    var hourdeg = ((hour%12)*3600+minute*60+second)/43200*360;
    var minutedeg = (minute*60+second)/3600*360;
    var seconddeg = second/60*360;
    $('.hour').css({'transform':'rotate('+hourdeg+'deg)'});
    $('.minute').css({'transform':'rotate('+minutedeg+'deg)'});
    $('.second').css({'transform':'rotate('+seconddeg+'deg)'});
  }

setTime();
```

```css
.second {
 max-height: 80%;
    margin-left: 20%;
 z-index: 11;
 -webkit-animation:spin 60s linear infinite;
    -moz-animation:spin 60s linear infinite;
    animation:spin 60s linear infinite;
}
@-moz-keyframes spin { 100% { -moz-transform: rotate(360deg); } }
@-webkit-keyframes spin { 100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); } }
@keyframes spin { 100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); transform:rotate(360deg); } }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src="http://moziru.com/images/clock-clipart-arrow-5.png" width="30px" height="300px" alt="second" title="second" class="clockHands second"/>
```

Comment: Maybe 12 is the default end point. Is it possible to set the end point yourself?

Comment: @Geshode Yes, when the page loads, 12 is the starting position of the arrows. Then I calculate the degree and use CSS to rotate the image to correct starting point.

Comment: How is the default starting point decided? Where is it defined?

Comment: @Geshode In a setTime() function. Variable seconddeg is a starting degree of the arrow, then I rotate them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're changing the rotation origin, instead of rotating from 0 to 360, you're rotating from 180 to 360.
this will cause the the animation to look slower and it will jump from 360 back to 180.

You can circumvent this by wrapping your spinning element with a wrapper, and rotate the wrapper instead.

```js
function setTime() {
  var time = new Date($.now());
  var hour = time.getHours();
  var minute = time.getMinutes();
  var second = time.getSeconds();
  var hourdeg = ((hour % 12) * 3600 + minute * 60 + second) / 43200 * 360;
  var minutedeg = (minute * 60 + second) / 3600 * 360;
  var seconddeg = second / 60 * 360;
  $('.hour').css({
    'transform': 'rotate(' + hourdeg + 'deg)'
  });
  $('.minute').css({
    'transform': 'rotate(' + minutedeg + 'deg)'
  });
  //$('.second').addClass('.instant')
  $('.second-wrapper').css({
    'transform': 'rotate(' + seconddeg + 'deg)'
  });

}

setTimeout(() => {
  setTime()
}, 500);
```

```css
.second-wrapper {
  transition: transform 2s ease;
  transform: rotate(0deg);
  transform-origin: center center;
  background-color: WhiteSmoke;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 20%;
}

.second {
  max-height: 80%;
  -webkit-animation: spin 60s linear infinite;
  -moz-animation: spin 60s linear infinite;
  animation: spin 60s linear infinite;
}

@-moz-keyframes spin {
  100% {
    -moz-transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes spin {
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

@keyframes spin {
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="second-wrapper">
  <img src="http://moziru.com/images/clock-clipart-arrow-5.png" width="30px" height="300px" alt="second" title="second" class="clockHands second" />
</div>
```